# How to get contents only written inside document(.doc, .docx, .pdf) with core php only without using phpWord or any other packages

Tags: php, laravel

I have a document and I want to read its content using php `file_get_contents()` method but this gives me some unwanted characters.
How can I remove these characters and get a clean output.

Here is the code that I use to get file contents using postman:-

```
public function file(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file'))
        {
            $file            = $request->file('file');
            $fileName        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path() . '/files/';
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $uploaded_file =  $fileName;

            $file_data = [
                'path' => $uploaded_file,
            ];

            $filename = $destinationPath.$fileName;

            $contents = file_get_contents($filename);

            $word = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\r\s@.,-,+,()]/","",$contents);
            dd($word); 
            //(this dd will show output with all contents but also gives some more characters)
            **(NOTE :- MY PROBLEM IS HERE)**

            $words =preg_replace("/['\t','\f','\r','\v']/","",$word);
            //dd($word, explode(' ',$words));
            $lines = explode(' ',$words);
            dd($lines);
            //(this dd will show output as an array)
        }
```

The bold dd gives me this output while the desired output is in bold text below :-

"""
\t(dddd SxSx l \f**Christopher MorganAddress 177 Great Portland Street, London W5W 6PQPhone +44 (0)20 7666 8555 Email christoper.morgan@gmail.comOBJECTIVE Provide analysis data support in a company as Data Analyst. WORK EXPERIENCE042014  04018Data Analyst, GHT Company, Madrid SpainResponsibilitiesEstablish operation strategy in a team for improving salesPrepare data and information for making regular report data analysisPerform data analysis for complex data and files032012   052014Data Analyst, Startup Corporation, Madrid SpainResponsibilitiesComposed Java program for interfacing with Oracle databasePerformed data analysis especially financial dataPerformed statistical data analysis using STATAShowed data analysis in regular meetings for creating new programEDUCATION 2004  2008Bachelor Degree of Computer Science, Technical University of Madrid2002  2004Certified as Data Analyst, Data Analyst Certification, Technical University of Madrid ADDITIONAL SKILLS Microsoft Office package Microsoft Word, Excel, AccessDatabase operation Microsoft Office Access, Oracle 8iStatistical operation SPSS, STATAProgramming C++, SQL, HTML REFERENCES References available on request**6
\f.vncXKOJQJCJ5BphOJQJCJ5BphOJQJCJBphOJQJCJBphOJQJCJ5OJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJ\f\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5OJQJCJ\f5OJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5OJQJCJ5OJQJCJ45BphOJQJCJ4Bph.\t\t\t
\f \f\f6\f8\fP\fR\f\f\f\f\f(yqjbTMFOJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJ\f\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5OJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5OJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5OJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJ\f\fOJQJCJOJQJCJBphOJQJCJ5BphOJQJCJ5BphOJQJCJBphOJQJCJBph(B\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJOJQJCJ5\fOJQJCJ\f\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJ\fOJQJCJ\t
\f\t\t\f \f0AAAAAAA0AAAAA \f\f6\f8\fR\f\f\f(A0AAAA0AAAAAAABA0AA
i4@4NormalCJOJPJQJmH\tA@Default Paragraph Font.\t
 \f\v\fGTimes New Roman5Symbol3Arial7Verdana 0hKlKl 0
Oh+0
.+,0\t
\v\f )Root Entry\tF+1TableWordDocumentSummaryInformation(DocumentSummaryInformation8
"""

Comment: tell me what character encoding the file has

Comment: I have to read data from any downloaded document file so here character encoding has not matter because a downloaded file can have any type of character encoding with it.

Comment: Character encoding of course DOES matter, or you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: sorry as i am new here and ok if character encoding matters then what if the character encoding is utf-8 type.

Comment: If everything is UTF-8 you shouldn't have issues. So something is different somewhere. Are your PHP scripts also UTF-8? (check your IDE or text editor)

Comment: what type of file is it? reading a docx, pdf or other format as string will o.c. return unreadable characters. Each dataformat has different metadata blocks, and other chunks of data, that is not readable for human

Comment: @delboy1978uk, yes my script supports utf-8 and i have checked same thing for a blank .doc file too and it also return some unwanted data as output containing document information like:- 
"""
\t ddddSxSxl\f\f \f \fOJQJCJ\f0
 P@
i4@4NormalCJOJPJQJmH\tA@Default Paragraph FontGTimes New Roman5Symbol3ArialHelvetica 0hKlKl 0
Oh+0
.+,0\t
\v\fRoot Entry\tF1TableWordDocumentSummaryInformation(DocumentSummaryInformation8
"""
(this is the output with a blank file)

Comment: @JarlikStepsto this is an .doc file(not .docx or pdf).
yes I know that different file format gives different data as I checked same for docx and pdf files too.